# Confusion related to a graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have this question related to this graph problem

Suppose that an n-node undirected graph G = (V , E) contains two nodes s and t such that the distance between s and t is strictly greater than n/2. Show that there must exist some node v, not equal to either s or t, such that deleting v from G destroys all s-t paths

Why is it that the distance between s and t is strictly greater than n/2.

```
1-2-3-4-5
|
6
|
7
```

Consider the above graph. 7 is one hop aways from 1. Total number of nodes n = 7. n/2=3. Even if 7 is less than n/2 hops away from 1, there is a node 6 which will separate 1 and 7 when cut. So I didn't get what this n/2 criteria is. I am not being able to visualize. Why is it necessary. Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove:

"there exist $s,t$ with $distance(s,t)\geq n/2$ $\Longrightarrow$ there exists $v$ which cuts off $s,t$

It sounds like you don't understand why $\Longleftarrow$ doesn't hold as well. For this you need to exhibit at least one counterexample. Take the complete graph of 3 vertices (a triangle):

```
  1
 / \
2 - 3
```

where the distance between any pair of nodes is 1, yet $n=3$ so $n/2=1.5$. Clearly 1,3 will remain connected if you remove 2.

To generalize this example to any $n$, think of $K_n$, the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Comment: I didn't get how this is a counter example. Any pair of nodes are at a distance 1 which is less than n/2=1.5. So obviously there is not cut off points

Comment: @user61169: You're asking why the $\geq n/2$ criterion is necessary. To see why it's necessary you need to stress-test situations where $<n/2$. It's necessary precisely because there are counterexamples if you are in the $<n/2$ situation.

Comment: Can u give me an example where it is strictly greater than n/2 and there is a cut off point?

Comment: How about your example, the numbers 5 and 7. Indeed, if you pick ANY two vertices in your example such that the distance between them is bigger than n/2, then there MUST exist a vertex that cuts them off. It just so happens though that in your example, some points with distance smaller than n/2 can also be cutoff. The point is you are assured 100% that you can cut the two points off with distance at least n/2. Any stronger result than this will heavily depend on extra structure in your graph.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the direct and converse implication...

It's like hearing a Theorem that "all penguins are black" and trying to argue that not all black things are penguins.

---

The Theorem only sais that if you can find two vertices with distance at least $n/2$ then something happens.

If two vertices have distance at least $n/2$, then you can use the Theorem...

If two vertices have distance less than $n/2$ the theorem says NOTHING. So in your graph the theorem sais absolutelly nothing about vertices 1 and 7....

And the reason why is necessary is this: consider the cycles $1,2,3$ and add vertices $4,5$ connected by $14$ and $25$. What is the distance between $4$ and $5$?

Comment: @N.S. the distance between 1 and 5 is 1. It is one hop away. The node 2 is between 1 and 5. So whats the point. I didn't get it

Comment: @user61169 Fixed the question... The point is that $\frac{n-1}{2}$ doesn't work...

Comment: Actually. I found that the solution to find it is something like this. BFS starting at node s until you find a node v that is in a layer by itself and delete that node thus disconnecting and possible connection from s to t. I didn't get how this is valid. How it actually is the solution. Any clarifications?